# Firebase storage local cache

Tags: firebase, caching, storage, traffic

We've prepared an app based on firebase storage and we plan to run it with few events. They're will be like 70 000 people. We assume there will be not many different files to download - for example a few video files, some more photos and sounds.

Assuming firebase storage could download 200-300MB each person we want to optimize the network traffic in specific location (one building).

Is there any possibility to create/run local storage cache not to skyrocket firebase storage bandwith, but only do this in local area (for people connected to some ours network)? Download it once to some local server and redirect all requests to it?

I'm looking for any kind of a solution.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for doesn't exactly exist within Firebase Storage.

However, you could work around your limitations by using a *link* to your content (e.g. on YouTube) and embedding it.

Alternatively, you could download content from your own server (or one hosted using Firebase Hosting) after you've pulled a list of metadata (links, names etc) from Firebase Storage. Using a CDN / caching service like Cloudflare would also mean that the impact on your server (or Firebase Hosting) is actually relatively low, as are costs.